# how to get out from error "Shared attribute in namespace ...... can be used only in compiled resource dictionaries." when using xaml in dll?

Tags: wpf

> Shared attribute in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
>   can be used only in compiled resource
>   dictionaries.

How to get out from this error, when working with xaml in dll/class library ?

Comment: Paste the xaml code where the error is happening.

Comment: It just say's error in{pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Resources/InternalResources.xaml} but there is no file like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/216762d4-ce21-4888-8d98-bbe4d30f7a03

In summary,  Shared is only legal under the following conditions:

- The ResourceDictionary that contains the items with x:Shared must be compiled.
- The ResourceDictionary cannot be within loose XAML or used for themes
- The ResourceDictionary that contains the items must not be nested within another ResourceDictionary. For instance, you cannot use x:Shared for items in a ResourceDictionary that is within a Style that is already a ResourceDictionary item

Comment: thanks finally i got it that x:Shared is only legal under the following conditions:

The ResourceDictionary that contains the items with x:Shared must be compiled. The ResourceDictionary cannot be within loose XAML or used for themes.

The ResourceDictionary that contains the items must not be nested within another ResourceDictionary. For instance, you cannot use x:Shared for items in a ResourceDictionary that is within a Style that is already a ResourceDictionary item.